# Gallery Implementation issue

Tags: android, android-widget

I am design a gallery which look like this [image: Gallery]

Now i have implemented gallery very nice .. now problem is the two dots coming below the image . 
Logic for Dots : black colour dot for selected image and selection of any dot image should change in gallery .

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) it may help you

Comment: @MAC : with View Pager i have one issue more ....with horizontal scroll ..if my scroll contains even small amt of  vertical component its not able to scroll but this is not there in gallery .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem like this 
1)Implemented this by having two galleries in Linear layout , one for the image gallery and other gallery for dot .
 
2)And this is how  i have integrated two

`iconGallery = (Gallery) view.findViewById(R.id.product_image_gallery_icon);
iconGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
gallery = (Gallery) view.findViewById(R.id.product_image_gallery);
GalleryImageAdapter adapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(getActivity(), urlList);
gallery.setAdapter(adapter);
gallery.setCallbackDuringFling(false);
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        GalleryIconAdapter galleryIconAdapter= new GalleryIconAdapter(getActivity(), dotCount, position);
        iconGallery.setAdapter(galleryIconAdapter);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});`

Pls update my someone finds a better solution .

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simply Check the logic like:

Current item visibility on screen based on that posiiton :

```
if(selectedItem == currentPosition){
Then display Black dotted image
}
in else
if position not matched with current item shown in gallery{

then default image will be appear...

}
```

i hope it helps :)